# Android Studio: "Gradle sync failed: Could not run JVM from the selected JDK."

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

Ever since installing Android Studio 3.2, I haven't been able to run Java, I have tried `jdk-8u181-windows-x64`, `jdk-10.0.2_windows-x64_bin`, `jdk-11_windows-x64_bin`, setting `PATH` and reinstalling everything umpteen times, the result is the same - no "java" appears and the error message is: -

> Gradle sync failed: Could not run JVM from the selected JDK.
>                     Please ensure JDK installation is valid and compatible with the current OS (Windows 8.1 6.3, amd64).
>                     If you are using embedded JDK, please make sure to download Android Studio bundle compatible
>                     with the current OS. For example, for x86 systems please choose a 32 bits download option. (369 ms)

Notes: I used to be able to open the java folder but after playing with it too much, something went wrong, so, I decided to start afresh... and I am dead ever since.

Is Studio 3.2 flawed? Not compatible with Java at all? Or am I missing something? is there a older Android Studio I can test? Thanks for any help you may provide.

Comment: add JAVA to system environment varibales. and also please add your logcat here.

Comment: And please share your `build.gradle` file as well.

Comment: Your current OS architecture is amd64 which means you probably should download JDK 64bit. Did you download that?

Answer (score 29):

In my case, the following solved it:

File->Other settings->Default Project Structure...

In "JDK Location", I previously had the oracle jdk selected. To fix this issue, I instead checked "Use embedded JDK (recommended)"

[image: Android Studio JDK location setting]

Comment: Mine was pointing to an old version of the Oracle SDK that had been uninstalled, but it also doesn't like JDK11 (ironically, it says "Select JDK8 or newer" when I have that selected). Using the embedded JDK fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

Solved YES
Other Settings ---> Default Project Structure ---> Uncheck Embedded jdk ( Write Your Own jdk Location )

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the following solved it:

File->Other settings->Default Project Structure...

setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181

my JDK Source File

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your SDK location. I had the same problem with Android Studio 3.2 (but I also switched to openjdk, so that could be the source of my problem). Anyway, after pointing SDK location to the root of my JDK it worked like a charm.
To change SDK location click on the Android project Window and then press F4. In the new Window choose SDK location and set it to point to the root of your JDK.

Answer (score 0):

i got mine working by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin my jdk folder