# Andriod Studio Gradle sync failed: Could not run JVM from the selected JDK.2

Tags: android-studio, gradle

[image: Pls Help me]

Gradle sync failed: Could not run JVM from the selected JDK.
            Please ensure JDK installation is valid and compatible with the current OS (Windows 7 6.1, x86).
            If you are using embedded JDK, please make sure to download Android Studio bundle compatible
            with the current OS. For example, for x86 systems please choose a 32 bits download option. (31 ms)

Comment: Please provide us with more information: you OS, your IDE, etc. Right now the information is very rough and not very useful...

Comment: My OS Is Windows 7 32bit

Comment: Jdk version I Downloaded the latest version of it

Comment: I'm not going to be able to help you on this one as I don't know Android Studio. However, you still miss some context on this error: when does the error happen? What were you trying to do? Tell us all you can do about it please, so people can have a better understanding of it :).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio: "Gradle sync failed: Could not run JVM from the selected JDK."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52584625/android-studio-gradle-sync-failed-could-not-run-jvm-from-the-selected-jdk)